# Would I lose the "Hurry up, it's raid night" after I earned it?

Tags: starcraft-2, achievements

Okay. **This is a silly question** but I have to know.

I recently completed the campaign in normal difficulty and got the achievement. I, now, want to get the brutal quests done. Is there a possibility that I play the same campaign missions on brutal over and over again and exceed the 8 hour limit for the achievement thus lose the achievement I already have?

Comment: In general you do not lose achievements once they are earned. I have yet to see a game that does the opposite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once an achievement is closed, you have it permanently.
It would be pretty stupid to stop you from replaying the game just because of an achievement.